# Hola , quiero leer los atributos de un XML , en si ya leo el contenido de las etiquetas , ahora quiero leer los atributos , estoy usando Dom4j

Tags: java, xml, java-8, java-ee, dom4j

**Hola , quiero leer los atributos de mi XML por medio de java usando Dom4j**

---

Para leer lo que esta dentro de la etiqueta estoy utilizando el sgnte codigo

```
try {
        File inputFile = new File("C:\\Users\\Seidor\\Documents\\xml1.xml");
        SAXReader reader = new SAXReader();
        Document document = reader.read( inputFile );
        
        System.out.println("Raiz del documento :" + document.getRootElement().getName());
        
        //lEER NODO ORDEN DE COMPRA
        Element classElement = document.getRootElement();
        List<Node> nodes = document.selectNodes("Invoice/cac:OrderReference");
        System.out.println("----------------------------");
       
        for (Node node : nodes) {
            System.out.println("\nCurrent Element :" + node.getName());
            System.out.println("Orden de compra : " + node.selectSingleNode("cbc:ID").getText());//OBTENEMOS LA ORDEN DE COMPRA
            valorOrdenCompra = node.selectSingleNode("cbc:ID").getText();
            
        } 
  } catch (DocumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: puedes poner un xml de ejemplo y que has intentado para leer los atributos para hacer mas clara la pregunta. igual te recomiendo leer el articulo [mcve]

Comment: En cada nodo puedes simplemente usar `nodo.attribute("nombreDelAtributo")` para obtener un objeto atributo del que puedes llamar `atributo.getName()` y `atributo.getValue()`. Si quieres iterar entre los atributos, los `Node`s tienen un método `attributeCount()` que te devuelve la cantidad de atributos que tiene y con  `attribute(i)` puedes obtener el íésimo atributo.